# Create 'cursor' in the middle of a word

Tags: javascript, css, css-float

I'm trying to make something in HTML/CSS/JS that looks like the cursor has been placed and frozen in the middle of a word. For now I have something like:

"Oran|ge"

but obviously that's not what it really looks like when you put the cursor in the middle of the word "Orange." I want it to look exactly the same but with a small vertical line between the 'n' and 'g'

Any help appreciated.

Comment: but what do you mean? you really want the cursor there or you just want some char which looks like a cursor?

Comment: http://fontawesome.io/icon/i-cursor/ maybe?

Comment: Sorry i wasn't clear. I want some char which looks like a cursor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this, I've added a blink animation for authenticity - the timing is a little off but it's close enough. Also note that I've set `contenteditable` on the example so you can compare the real insertion-point cursor side by side.

```css
.insertion-point {
    width: 0;
    display: inline;
    margin-right: -1px;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    animation: ip-blink .89s steps(2, start) infinite;
}

@keyframes ip-blink {
    to {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
}
```

```html
<p contenteditable="true">Oran<span class="insertion-point"></span>ge
```

It's worth noting that this scales with font-size accurately.

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you!

Comment: Nice, +1 for blinking :)

Answer (score 1):

Will this be an option, where a pseudo is used, together with a negative margin.

```css
span::after {
  content: '∣';
  font-size: 125%;
  margin: 0 -2px;
}
```

```html
"Ora<span>n</span>ge"
```

Here using its border

```css
span::after {
  content: '';
  border-left: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
"Ora<span>n</span>ge"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```css
.box-cont{position: relative;margin: 0px 2px;}
.cursor{position:absolute;width: 1px; height: 20px; background: black;}
```

```html
"Oran<span class="box-cont"><span class="cursor"></span></span>ge"
```

```
"Oran<span class="box-cont"><span class="cursor"></span></span>ge"
```